# Joining Statements IN MVC 4

Tags: sql

I am trying to find the right syntax for my statement but I am lost... What I have is a table that has Manufacturers Names, a table that has all the different types of cards, and a Table that houses all the information for my cards. What I want to do is once a manufacturer is selected I want to query the Cards table for all the entries that have the same Manufacturer Id and get the different types from there, group the types then display their names to the browser.

```
Manufacturers Table:
Id || Name

Types Table:
Id || Name

Cards Table:
Id || Manufacturer || Type || Set || Year || Number || Name || Team || Quantity || Price
```

What I have that semi-works (it displays the same Type Names multiple times):

```
var ts = db.Query(@"SELECT Types.Id, Types.Name FROM Types LEFT OUTER JOIN Cards ON Types.Id = Cards.Type WHERE Manufacturer=@0 ORDER BY Types.Name", ManId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `DISTINCT` to your `SELECT` statement.

```
var ts = db.Query(@"SELECT DISTINCT Types.Id, Types.Name FROM Types LEFT OUTER JOIN Cards ON Types.Id = Cards.Type WHERE Manufacturer=@0 ORDER BY Types.Name", ManId).ToList();
```